# Google Map add marker from two text boxes values (lat & lng)

Tags: google-maps

I have an app where the user clicks on the map to create a marker and store it in the database.
This code under my question works fine, but now I would like to add a function to display a marker from lat and lng values ​​contained in two text boxes (camera_lat and camera_long) imported from the database.
Does anyone know how to do that ?

```
let map;
var marker;

function initmap() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.920340, 7.1325917);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: latlng,
        gestureHandling: 'greedy'   
    };  

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("div_map"), myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {

        // get lat/lon of click
        clickLat = event.latLng.lat();
        clickLon = event.latLng.lng();

        // show in input box
        document.getElementById("camera_lat").value = clickLat.toFixed(5);
        document.getElementById("camera_long").value = clickLon.toFixed(5);

        // if marker exist remove it show only one marker
        if(marker != null){
            marker.setMap(null);
        }

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(clickLat,clickLon),
            map: map
            });
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initmap);
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the posted code?

Comment: This code works fine but i would like to add a function to display a marker from lat and lng values ​​contained in two textboxes and i dont know how to do that. Maybe with reverse geocoding but exemples are with only one textbox input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take the values from the input fields, use them to make a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) object, use that to position the marker.

1. make a function to add the marker:

```
function addMarker(latLng, map) {
  // if marker exist remove it show only one marker
  if (marker != null) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  }

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });
}
```

2. if you want to add the marker on page load (and have data in the input fields at that time, call the function after instantiating the map:

```
  var lat = document.getElementById("camera_lat").value;
  var lng = document.getElementById("camera_long").value;
  addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), map);
```

3. then use that in the existing code and in a click listener function on a button to add the marker:

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
    var lat = document.getElementById("camera_lat").value;
    var lng = document.getElementById("camera_long").value;
    addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), map);
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/phbedko6/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;
var marker;

function initmap() {

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.920340, 7.1325917);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: latlng,
    gestureHandling: 'greedy'
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("div_map"), myOptions);

  var lat = document.getElementById("camera_lat").value;
  var lng = document.getElementById("camera_long").value;
  addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {

    // get lat/lon of click
    clickLat = event.latLng.lat();
    clickLon = event.latLng.lng();

    // show in input box
    document.getElementById("camera_lat").value = clickLat.toFixed(5);
    document.getElementById("camera_long").value = clickLon.toFixed(5);

    addMarker(event.latLng, map);
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click', function() {
    var lat = document.getElementById("camera_lat").value;
    var lng = document.getElementById("camera_long").value;
    addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), map);
  });
}

function addMarker(latLng, map) {
  // if marker exist remove it show only one marker
  if (marker != null) {
    marker.setMap(null);
  }

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initmap);
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#div_map {
  height: 90%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <input id="camera_lat" value="43.661" />
  <input id="camera_long" value="6.90188" />
  <input id="btn" value="add marker" type="button" />
  <div id="div_map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
</body>

</html>
```